# add Property Key Cardinality

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am working with JanusGraph db. I am trying to add Property Key Cardinality.
Here I am creating new property of vertex.

> ```
> name = mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
> ```

But it doesn't work! And I have this mistake:

```
Adding this property for key [~T$SchemaName] and value [rtname] violates a uniqueness constraint [SystemIndex#~T$SchemaName]
```

I find this solution but it doesn't work too.

```
mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).cardinality(org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
```

But it doesn't work too and I have the same mistake.
So, how can I set this Cardinality type while adding property key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems to suggest that the property key already exists. Can you verify by doing `mgmt.printSchema()` and checking the output? This is a comment but I'm using the answer section as I do not have enough reputation.